# Gallery with custom handlers are not working in fancybox V4

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I was trying to create gallery with fancybox v4.0.5, It is working perfectly with default handler but with custom, model is opening but slider is not working.

## Here is the code===

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
<div class="grid imglist">
    <div class="row padding-bottom--sm">
        <a class="col col--4" data-custombox="demo" data-src="https://lipsum.app/id/1/1024x768" data-caption="<b>Hello, There!</b> <br /> This is a multi-line caption"><img src="https://lipsum.app/id/1/400x300"></a>
        <a class="col col--4" data-custombox="demo" data-src="https://lipsum.app/id/2/1024x768" data-caption="Optional caption"><img src="https://lipsum.app/id/2/400x300"></a>
        <a class="col col--4" data-custombox="demo" data-src="https://lipsum.app/id/5/1024x768"><img src="https://lipsum.app/id/5/400x300"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a class="col col--6" data-custombox="demo" data-src="https://lipsum.app/id/3/1024x512"><img src="https://lipsum.app/id/3/500x250"></a>
        <a class="col col--6" data-custombox="demo" data-src="https://lipsum.app/id/4/1024x512"><img src="https://lipsum.app/id/4/500x250"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    Fancybox.bind("[data-custombox]", {});
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your code snippet works perfectly fine, see this demo - https://fancyapps.com/playground/Xm

Next, why are you using `$(window).load(function() {})`? Not only it is redundant, but it is removed in jQuery v3, therefore your code will never be executed.

Edit: I added `groupAttr: "data-custombox"` option to group items.